# Using 3 'for' loops to integrate functions and return a 3d array in python is too slow, how can I optimize it?

Tags: python, arrays

I have 3 arrays of data to integrate over and need to return a 3d array. This is my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
def f(x, y, z):
    return x + y + 2*z

a = np.arange(64)
b = np.arange(100)
c = np.arange(100)

result = []
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        for z in c:
            result.append(integrate.quad(f, 0, x, (y, z))[0])

result_1 = np.array(result).reshape(len(a), len(b), len(c))
print(result_1)
```

It works, but this code is so slow and I need to handle problems bigger than this. Is there any other method, something like broadcasting? And the following is the function I need to handle:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate, special

def f(v,r):
    alpha = 0.5
    chi = 1/2*special.erf((r+1.2)/0.3)-1/2*special.erf((r-1.2)/0.3)
    return 4/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*alpha))*chi*np.exp(-v**2/(2*alpha))

def E_1(r):

    def f_1(v,r):
        return r*f(v,r)

    a = 0 
    b = r
    g = lambda x: -np.inf
    h = lambda x: np.inf
    return integrate.dblquad(f_1, a, b, g, h)

def E_f(tau, xi_1, xi_2):
    return E_1(xi_1*np.cos(tau) + xi_2*np.sin(tau))[0]*(-np.sin(tau))
```

I need to input tau, xi_1, xi_2 as three arrays, and return to a 3D array. And its arrange like coordinate, every coordinate point corresponds to a result. Just like the first example.

Comment: try using list comprehension, it is more pythonic and faster than normal for loops

Comment: Is that the excat function you need to integrate? It is easily doable by hand.

Comment: @Shubham Namdeo, It looks conciser. But it is not faster, I just tried it . Thank you anyway

Comment: @Julien, It's not the exact function I need to integrate, I just use this function to test. My function is very complex.

Comment: well unless you give us the exact function there's not much we can do to help.